# The iOS SDK version '...' is not installed, and no newer version was found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I get the error **after updating Xamarin** in Visual Studio which I had to do **after a git pull**.  I have also applied the **Xamarin updates** in Xamarin Studio on my Mac build host.  (Xamarin Studio > Check for updates).

```
The iOS SDK version '9.2' is not installed, and no newer version was found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XCode needed updating** to get the latest SDK.

The App Store told me there were updates, and mentioned SDK 9.2 in the summary so I updated.

It appears the cause was a commit on the csproj that bumped the SDK.

Answer (score 6):

You can also modify the SDK version of your iOS project from visual studio in order to support older SDKs where you cant update the XCode or SDKs.

1. Open **iOS project properties** from Visual Studio.
2. Open **iOS.Build** tab
3. Set **SDK version** to 'Default'
4. Set **Link Behaviour** to 'Link Framework SDKs Only'
5. Save and Run the project

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can manually edit .csproj file and replace `<MtouchSdkVersion>9.2</MtouchSdkVersion>` with the version you actually have on your mac. This can be a solution when you use an old OS which does not offer updates for XCode.